# Thumbnails animation like Apples Photos app in iOS9

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

I have currently a UICollectionView with a custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout that is snapping the center image and when i swipe the big image it the thumbnails go with it and vice versa.

Now i want the center image to be animate just like the Photos app in iOS9
Can anyone help with archive this animation? And with full image and more spacing only around the center image

[image: Apple Photos app]